# DB2 - Modifies SQL Data

Tags: sql, db2

I have a stored procedure in db2 that is causing sqlcode=-577 errors.  The reason for this i think is that i have not set the 'modifies sql data' clause on my procedure.  is there any way to do an alter procedure to set this clause, or will i have to drop and recreate the procedure?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you will have to recreate the procedure as **[ALTER PROCEDURE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0008168.htm)** cannot set that bit. Fortunately it's not terribly complicated to do so.